# Developing gems and using them in rails projects with bundler, is there a faster way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, rubygems, bundler

I'm writing a gem for a Rails project and committing changes to its git repository. The Rails project refers to it in the Gemfile.

```
gem "blah", :git => "blah", :branch => "development"
```

The problem is one of patience. Every time I commit changes to the gem, I have to run "bundle update" (or at least `bundle update blah`) to be able to use the gem, which takes a while. Is there a way of bypassing the bundle update step and using the latest version of the gem whenever I restart my Rails app?

Comment: Related question: Is there a way to automatically load the changes to the gem *without* restarting the Rails app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First:

Use a path:

```
gem "blah", :path => "~/Code/blah"
```

Second (to answer Zabba's question-as-a-comment): No it's currently not possible to automatically reload your gems in development mode. You must restart your server each time you change your gem.

A better way would be to generate your gem with a dummy application included in its test suite and test against that.